# Angular 9 children route module not loading

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript

I'm creating an application with Angular 9 where I've created a separate routing module for the admin purpose and calling it in app.module to initialize. But for some reason the routes are not getting called and and the below error is coming in the console.

> ERROR Error
>       Angular 11
>           resolvePromise
>           resolvePromise
>           scheduleResolveOrReject
>           invokeTask
>           onInvokeTask
>           invokeTask
>           runTask
>           drainMicroTaskQueue
>           invokeTask
>           invoke
>           timer
>           core.js:3872

I've created child modules like this in previous versions of Angular and it worked perfectly. You can check my github repository if you want to https://github.com/tridibc2/sample-angular. Have a look at my modules below

AdminModule:

```
import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';
import { CommonModule } from '@angular/common';
import { Routes, RouterModule } from '@angular/router';
import { FormsModule, ReactiveFormsModule } from '@angular/forms';

import { AdminComponent } from '../admin/admin.component';
import { SignupComponent } from '../signup/signup.component';
import { LoginComponent } from '../login/login.component';
import { ManageBlogsComponent } from '../manage-blogs/manage-blogs.component';

const routes: Routes = [
  { path: 'signup', component: SignupComponent },
  { path: 'login', component: LoginComponent },
    { path: 'admin', component: AdminComponent },
   { path: 'admin/blog', component: ManageBlogsComponent }
];

@NgModule({
  declarations: [
    AdminComponent,
    SignupComponent,
    LoginComponent,
    ManageBlogsComponent
  ],
  imports: [
    RouterModule.forChild(routes),
    CommonModule,
    FormsModule,
    ReactiveFormsModule
  ],
  exports: [RouterModule]
})
export class AdminModule { }
```

app.module.ts:

```
import { BrowserModule } from '@angular/platform-browser';
import { HttpClientModule } from '@angular/common/http';
import { CommonModule } from '@angular/common';
import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';
import { FormsModule } from '@angular/forms';
import { NgbModule } from '@ng-bootstrap/ng-bootstrap';
import { RouterModule } from '@angular/router';
import { ClientModule } from './client/client-routing/client.module';
import { AdminModule } from './admin/admin-routing/admin.module';
import { AppRoutingModule } from './app.routing';
import { AppComponent } from './app.component';

@NgModule({
  declarations: [
    AppComponent ],
  imports: [
    BrowserModule,
    CommonModule,
    NgbModule,
    ClientModule,
    AdminModule,
    AppRoutingModule,
    FormsModule,
    RouterModule ],

   bootstrap: [AppComponent]
})
export class AppModule { }
```

app.routing.ts:

```
import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';
import { CommonModule, } from '@angular/common';
import { BrowserModule  } from '@angular/platform-browser';
import { Routes, RouterModule } from '@angular/router';
import { BlogHomeComponent } from './client/blog-home/blog-home.component';
const routes: Routes =[
    { path: '', redirectTo: 'home', pathMatch: 'full' },
    { path: 'home',             component: BlogHomeComponent }
];

@NgModule({
  imports: [
    CommonModule,
    BrowserModule,
    RouterModule.forRoot(routes,{
      useHash: true
    })
  ],
  exports: [
  ],
})
export class AppRoutingModule { }
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Simple example for routing of eager loaded module. 
Ref of atleast one component is required in parent module and which is mostly a component that has `router-outlet` tag to render child module routes.

```
...

const routes: Routes = [
  { 
    path: '', 
    component: CompWhichHasRouterOutletTag,
    children:[
      {path: '', redirectTo: 'signup', pathMatch: 'full'},
      { path: 'signup', component: SignupComponent },
      { path: 'login', component: LoginComponent },
      { path: 'admin', component: AdminComponent },
      { path: 'admin/blog', component: ManageBlogsComponent }]
    }

];

@NgModule({
  declarations: [
    CompWhichHasRouterOutletTag,
    AdminComponent,
    SignupComponent,
    LoginComponent,
    ManageBlogsComponent
  ],
  imports: [
    RouterModule.forChild(routes),
    CommonModule,
    FormsModule,
    ReactiveFormsModule
  ],
  exports: [RouterModule, CompWhichHasRouterOutletTag]
})
export class AdminModule { }
```

app.routing.ts file

```
const routes: Routes = [
  { path: '', redirectTo: '/home/', pathMatch: 'full' },
  { path: 'home', component: HomeComponent },
  { path: 'contact', component: ContactComponent },
  { path: 'admin-route', component: CompWhichHasRouterOutletTag },
]
@NgModule({
  imports: [
    ...

    RouterModule.forRoot(routes),

    ...
  ]
})
```

Comment: upon adding the adminComponent having router-outlet in exports of AdminRoutingModule is fetching this error in console ---- Unhandled Promise rejection: Can't export component AdminComponent from AdminRoutingModule as it was neither declared nor imported!

Comment: In order to access one module component | pipe | directives you have to export from that module. That's why i have only exported `CompWhichHasRouterOutletTag` from AdminRoutingModule and used in app,routes.ts using `admin-route` which will initiate Routing in AdminRoutingModule and it's childrens

Comment: but it's not working that way..noting gets on the view and the above error is coming on the console. I can share the code on github it you want to check

Comment: @surjendu_dey share a repo link.